# Code working in IE but not in FF

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a requirement that the user will type in a textbox and the textbox will be filed with suggestions from the database. The user then will select the option and on clicking add button this text will be added as a tag in dynamic html table so that it can be removed later. I have everything working fine but the problem is that my code is only working in IE. When running the page in Firefox it is not running and also it is not showing any error. For the testing purpose i have replaced the hiddenfields with textboxes. You can type in "Text" and "Value" textboxes and click on Add Skill buttons. It will work in IE but not in FF. Waiting for the suggestions. Here is the complete code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="AddSkills.aspx.cs" Inherits="AddSkills" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>AutoComplete</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .wrapper
        {
            background-color: Silver;
            width: auto;
        }
        .selecteditem
        {
            font-family: Verdana,Arial,Times New Roman;
            font-size: 10px;
        }
        .selecteditemClose
        {
            font-family: Verdana,Arial,Times New Roman;
            font-size: 11px;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: Red;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        .selecteditemClose:hover
        {
            color: Maroon;
        }
    </style>

    <script src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function addRow() {
            var selectedText = $("#txtSkills").val();
            var selectedValue = $("#selectedID").val();
            var newRow = document.all("tblGrid").insertRow();
            var oCell = newRow.insertCell();

            if (selectedText == '') {
                alert('Please select a skill.');
                return false;
            }
            else {
                var addedID = $("#addedID").val();
                if (addedID != '') {
                    if (addedID.indexOf(',' + selectedValue + ',') != -1) {
                        alert('Skill already selected.');
                        $("#txtSkills").val('');
                        $("#selectedID").val('');
                        return false;
                    }
                    else {
                        oCell.innerHTML = "<span class='wrapper'><span class='selecteditem'>" + selectedText + "</span>&nbsp;<span class='selecteditemClose' onclick=\"removeRow(this,'" + selectedValue + "');\">x</span></span>";
                        appendSelectedID(selectedValue);
                        $("#txtSkills").val('');
                        $("#selectedID").val('');
                    }
                }
                else {
                    oCell.innerHTML = "<span class='wrapper'><span class='selecteditem'>" + selectedText + "</span>&nbsp;<span class='selecteditemClose' onclick=\"removeRow(this,'" + selectedValue + "');\">x</span></span>";
                    appendSelectedID(selectedValue);
                    $("#txtSkills").val('');
                    $("#selectedID").val('');
                }
            }
        }


        function removeRow(src, removedValue) {
            removeSelectedID(removedValue);
            var oRow = src.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement;
            document.all("tblGrid").deleteRow(oRow.rowIndex);
        }
        function appendSelectedID(selectedValue) {
            if ($("#addedID").val() == '')
                $("#addedID").val(',');
            $("#addedID").val($("#addedID").val() + selectedValue + ',');
        }
        function removeSelectedID(removedValue) {
            var addedID = $("#addedID").val();
            var modifiedID = addedID.replace(',' + removedValue + ',', ',');
            $("#addedID").val(modifiedID);
            if ($("#addedID").val() == ',')
                $("#addedID").val('');
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        Text:<asp:TextBox ID="txtSkills" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <%--These textboxes are supposed to be hidden fields. For the testing purpose they are used as textboxes--%>
        Value:<asp:TextBox ID="selectedID" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        Collective Values:<asp:TextBox ID="addedID" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <input type="button" value="Select Skill" onclick="return addRow();" />
        <table id="tblGrid" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" width="250px">
        </table>
        <br />    


    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`document.all` is not available in Firefox. It's a proprietary IE method, that's also adopted by webkit and Opera, but not Firefox.

You should try sticking to jQuery, which is cross browser, instead of mixing native JS and jQuery!

Comment: +1, but you should also have mentioned that `document.getElementById()` is a perfectly good replacement for most usages of `document.all()`. And it's fine to mix JS and jQuery if you know what you're doing. jQuery is great, but in some cases it's quicker and just as easy to use the standard DOM.

Comment: @Spudley - that's true in many cases, but using parentElement three times, document.all and a lot of other quirks in the OP's code, makes me think it's probably better to just stick with jQuery for everything.

Comment: Thankss guys. I have replaced document.All with document.getElementById and its working. Now the only problem remaining is when I click to remove a row, the id is removed from the textbox but the HTML for the row in table remains intact. adeneo is right that maybe using parentElement thre times is creating the problem. The reason to mix jquery and native JS is because I have to create a dynamic table and I could not find a good example how to do that so I used the one which was available in JS. Can anyone tell me how do I remove a row using JS or JQuery? My table has only one cell each row.

Comment: `$("#tblGrid").find('tr').remove();`

Comment: Thanks adeneo. your code is removing all the elements(added tags) on clicking any tag.

Comment: It's an example of how to remove a row, you'll have to figure out the selectors, but if it triggers on any tag, I'd like to remind you that ID's are unique, and you can't have more than one #tblGrid element in the document at any given time.